# Could I enable ROCE v2 on both MCX623106AN-CDAT 100GbE NIC cards and connect each other without any switch?

Tags: windows, mellanox, rdma

Since I do not have ROCE v2 supported switch, and I am planning to connect two MCX623106AN-CDAT 100GbE NIC cards each other from two different server systems, the OS I plan to use is Windows Server 2022, so, I’d like to understand if it is possible to run ROCE v2 feature without switch by direct connect between two NIC cards?

BTW, is there any guidance that I can referred to for configuring ROCE v2 on both MCX623106AN-CDAT NIC cards and without a switch?

Thank you!
Jacky

Comment: Hi sir,

I have googled and seems the Connect-X 6 Dx datasheet shows the card does not support ECN and PFC, does that mean I really need a supported switch to have the Flow Control for lossless network?

Thanks,
Jacky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From nVIDIA employee:
ConnectX-6 Dx supports ECN and PFC. It does have a mode “Zero-touch RoCE” which does not require ECN and PFC.
There should not be any issue connecting the servers back to back without a switch.